# Update to replace specific value with another except when it already exists

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete, exists

I have a table with values like this:

```
...
jack     |  woo
...
james    |  poo
james    |  woo
...
john     |  poo
...
```

There's also a UNIQUE constraint on both columns

**I want to change all 'poo' to 'woo', as long as it doesn't violate the constraint, and then delete the remaining 'poo'**, in order to obtain this table:

```
...
jack     |  woo
...
james    |  woo
...
john     |  woo
...
```

My attempts to far for the first step:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET lastname='woo' WHERE lastname='poo'
```

> Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: [..]

```sql
UPDATE MyTable SET lastname='woo' WHERE lastname='poo'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.lastname='woo')
```

> Result: [..] 0 rows affected

This is an action I'm executing in sqlite-browser, and I'll probably need it only a couple dozen or so times. So the solution doesn't need to be very efficient or single-query.

Since my database isn't 'live' I can also, for example, temporarily disable constraint checking, execute my first query, and then clean up duplicates (how?)

Comment: SQLite supports ignore_check_constraints PRAGMA statement with which you enable/disable CHECK constraints, but there is no equivalent to enable/disable UNIQUE constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correlate the subquery:

```
UPDATE MyTable AS t1 
SET lastname = 'woo' 
WHERE t1.lastname = 'poo'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2 WHERE (t2.firstname, t2.lastname) = (t1.firstname, 'woo'));
```

And then delete the remaining rows:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE lastname = 'poo';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dd53cf8795e0c76b904ac8ed1c4ec536).

Comment: For some reason it works in your demo but not in my actual database. Getting '0 rows affected'. I triple-checked if I replaced all dummy names with real names correctly. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus execute a select statement before the update statement: `SELECT t1.* 
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE t1.lastname = 'poo'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2 WHERE (t2.firstname, t2.lastname) = (t1.firstname, 'woo'));` to check if there are any rows that should be updated: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ae28d004af581baec74ef56dfcae35e3

Comment: Ok so it turned out with the data I used, all instances were duplicates, like `james` in my toy example.